# How to make 5 API get requests and pass data to one view?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make 5 API calls in one route and pass the data to one view file.

APIs (only change is chain parameter):

```
https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=1&account=ARDOR-XJRL-GPRK-QRUS-C73SE
https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=2&account=ARDOR-XJRL-GPRK-QRUS-C73SE
https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=3&account=ARDOR-XJRL-GPRK-QRUS-C73SE
https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=4&account=ARDOR-XJRL-GPRK-QRUS-C73SE
https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=5&account=ARDOR-XJRL-GPRK-QRUS-C73SE
```

I followed a tutorial to get 2 of the API calls to work, but can't figure out 3+.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});

var Ardor = {
    url: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=1&account=ARDOR-9P55-NZTA-ME3E-DBZE4"
};

var Ignis = {
    url: "https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=2&account=ARDOR-9P55-NZTA-ME3E-DBZE4"
};

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    function callback(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            request(Ignis, (error, response, body) => {
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                    var data2 = JSON.parse(body);
                    res.render("resultsAccountId", {data1: data, data2: data2});
                }    
            });
        }
    }    
    request(Ardor, callback);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
   console.log("Blockchain Explorer has started!"); 
});
```

How can I make this work so that I can have variables data1, data2, data3, data4, data5 all passed to one view page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are several ways to do this, one of them is use the request-promise module which is an extensive request module only as a promise, so we can use await to wait for the promise to finish collecting the request data.

> [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

Change the `request` module by `request-promise`

This

```
var request = require("request");
```

for that

```
var request = require('request-promise')
```

**Result:**

Add async to the request so that you can expect all the promises. I created a for for 5 get requests by changing the value of the chain going from 1 to 5 and getting the data in json and adding it to a list. Remembering the end result is a list of objects that can be mapped or accessed by data [0], data [1], data [2] ... data[4].

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var request = require('request-promise')
var path = require('path');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/results", async function(req, res){
    const data = [];
    for(let chain=1; chain<6; chain++){
        let val = await request({
            method: 'get',
            uri: `https://testardor.jelurida.com/nxt?requestType=getBalance&chain=${chain}&account=ARDOR-9P55-NZTA-ME3E-DBZE4`,
            json: true
        })
        data.push(val);
    }
    //res.send(data)
    res.render('resultsAccountId',{data})
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
  console.log("Blockchain Explorer has started!"); 
});
```

data[0]

```
{ unconfirmedBalanceNQT: '771177340000',
  balanceNQT: '771177340000',
  requestProcessingTime: 0 
}
```

Comment: If possible, accept the answer as the best. Select the bookmark to the left of the response.